# Trying to use a 'where' in query against object relationship in Hasura

Tags: graphql, hasura

So I've got a table (call it authors) that I'm joining using an object relationship to another (call it articles). Although, it's not a proper one-to-one relationship as obviously an author can have numerous articles. The reason I'm using an object relationship is so that I'm able to sort by articles (which an array relationship doesn't allow). This is all fine but I want to narrow down the query by using a 'where' for the articles, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

An example query would look like

```
query testQuery {
   authors(
      where: {
         name: {_eq: "Jeff"}
         articles: {
            id: {_eq: 1}
         }
      }
   ) {
       id
       name
       articles {
          id
          title
          topic
       }
   }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get around this without having to do a manual filter on the results... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is good, but are you sure you actually have any result that have name: "Jeff" for the id:1 article ?
I would try to remove the name condition for now, to confirm that the articles where works

Comment: That's just used as an example, the only part that isn't actually working is the 'articles' part.

Comment: well, that should definitely work. Can you show us your table structure?